# How to check multi columns if null then use the next column in order?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have 4 columns and would like to check them in order if Column one is not null use it, else use column 2 Then if column 2 is null then use column 3 and if column 3 is null use column 4 else leave null.

here is what I have, but does not check all columns.

`Case
    WHEN SEGMENT1 IS Null THEN SEGMENT2
    WHEN SEGMENT2 IS Null THEN SEGMENT3
    WHEN SEGMENT3 IS Null THEN SEGMENT4
    Else SEGMENT1
 END AS Segment`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`COALESCE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_coalesce.html) (an ISO/ANSI standard SQL method) where as specified in docs:

> The arguments are evaluated in the order in which they are specified, and the result of the function is the first argument that is not null. The result can be null only if all arguments can be null.

```
COALESCE(SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3, SEGMENT4) AS Segment
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic you describe looks like this:

```
(CASE WHEN SEGMENT1 IS NOT Null THEN SEGMENT1
      WHEN SEGMENT2 IS NOT Null THEN SEGMENT2
      WHEN SEGMENT3 IS NOT Null THEN SEGMENT3
      ELSE SEGMENT4
 END) AS Segment
```